# How find out TClientSocket is active

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

my application has a TClientsocket connect to server properly
but when sever shut down and run again
my application does not know to connect to it

i use this code to solve problem

```
if not ClientSocke.active then
    begin
        clintsocke.open();
    end
else
    Exit();
```

but this code does not solve my problem and active property is false always
how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Checking for `Active=false` will work just fine.  But you should also be handling the `OnDisconnect` and `OnError` events as well.  In `OnError` in particular, you can `Close()` the socket.

Also, if possible, you should implement pings/keepalives in your communication protocol, so you can detect when the server stops responding to commands.  If you send a command and get a socket error, close the socket.  If you send a command and don't get a response in a timely manner, close the socket.

If that is not possible, then you should at least enable TCP keepalives via `setsockopt()`, so the OS can report errors on sockets that stop responding.